# How to find driver id by i2cget

Tags: linux, driver, embedded-linux, i2c, device-tree

I Get the list of detected peripherals on the specific I2C - 4:

```any
# i2cdetect -y 4 

     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: 70 71 -- -- -- -- -- --
```

How can I find drivers id about devices on this bus (i2c-4)?

Comment: There is no way. I²C is **not** discoverable bus. You have to know ahead what devices are connected. Otherwise you missed to name them in your question. Also confusing the `device-tree` tag. Do you want to describe them there, or they are already there?

Comment: My device tree is not built correctly for the current embedded Linux. I want to rewrite the device tree myself and recompile the image. And available utilities on the current embedded linux i2detect / dump / get / set.
Using them, it is not possible to find the correct driver id for further dt construction.
There is an idea to rewrite sensors-detect (lm-sensors) from Perl to C, namely the i2c module (because there is no perl on embedded Linux and I cannot run the sensors -detect script).

p.s. I don't have a motherboard schematic to describe the dt

Comment: Then find a schematic first. There is **no other way** to know what exactly is there. Moreover, there is a potentially dangerous discovery options on some hardware, if wrong sequence is used you may damage your hardware for real (with a smoke and everything).